# Any hints on making a website auto resize in browser?

Tags: css, web, resize

I am almost done editing a new website template I bought. I really like the site, but I have just noticed it seems to have been made for only one resolution type. So, if I view it on a lower resolution screen... I can't see the whole site (can't even scroll down!). Then, on a high resolution screen, the site is so small I can barely read the text. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Below is a link of the original template so you can better understand what I'm talking about [this](http://themedemo.indonez.com/?theme=Mixel).

Answer (score 0):

There is something called media query in css where you can change the styling of your site based on the device.

If you want certain css styles for big screens then do this

```
@media(min-width:1200px){
  .yourClassName {
    //css style
  }
}
```

Similarly for small devices,
write a media query for smaller devices.

Thank you.